# Getting Connection refused while trying to access service from kubernetes pod

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod

I am new to kubernetes and I am trying to learn it by deploying a simple node server using AWS EKS. (kubernetes is alreay setup to talk to the created AWS EKS cluster)

Here is code for my simple node file (`server.js`)

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8080

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Here is how the `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM node:12
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
# Bundle app source
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

I am able to run the above server in my local by creating a docker image.

Now, in order to deploy this server here are the steps that I followed: 
First, I pushed the above image to doceker hub (aroraankit7/simple-server)
Second, I created a deployment.yaml file which looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: simple-server-app
  labels:
    app: simple-server-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: simple-server-app
   template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         app: simple-server-app
     spec:
       containers:
       - name: simple-server
         image: aroraankit7/simple-server:v1
         ports:
         - containerPort: 8080
```

Third, I deployed this using kubectl apply command. Here is the output for `kubectl get pods`
[image]

Then, I created the service.yaml file. Here is how it looks:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: simple-server-svc
labels:
  run: simple-server
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    run: simple-server
```

I then deployed this using the kubectl apply command. Output for `kubectl describe services`:
[image]

Next, I logged into on of my pods by using the command: `kubectl -it exec simple-server-app-758dfb88f4-4cfmp bash`

While inside this pod, I ran the following the command: `curl http://simple-server-svc:8080` and this was the output that I got: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to simple-server-svc port 8080: Connection refused`

Why is the connection getting refused?

When I am running `curl http:localhost://8080`, I am getting the right output (Hello World! in this case)

Comment: If you take a look at the `Endpoints` in your service description, you see `<none>`...and that's because you are using the wrong selector....change your service selector to `app: simple-server-app` and then when you run `kubectl describe` you should see 2 endpoints 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service is not bound to the deployment. You need to modify the selector in your service.yaml to the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: simple-server-svc
 labels:
  run: simple-server
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: simple-server-app
```

You can use kubectl expose command to avoid mistakes like this.

Comment: Thanks @Sunitha
What is the difference between "app" and "run"?

Comment: It's an arbitrary choice of label, but the Service needs to match the Pods.